# How to draw Image on right bottom corner of the canvas?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-canvas

In My application i want to set the image on the canvas at the right bottom corner.
So How i have to set that image in canvas ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap , canvas.getWidth()-bitmap.getWidth()  , canvas.getHeight()-bitmap.getHeight() , paint);

Answer (score 2):

Get the `x and y` coordinates by some simple calculation

Pseudo Code

```
x = canvas.width - image.width - padding
y = canvas.height - image.height - padding
canvas.drawBitmap(x,y,....)
```

EDIT: `x = Math.max(0,x);` and `y = Math.max(0,y);` incase the image is bigger than the canvas.